# play video inside view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have to play 3 videos inside view pager and I am using PagerAdapter to go to different pages. 
I am facing some problems : On the first time, the first video does not render, it shows a black screen.
My second video runs only the first time when visited. Other videos run again when I visit that page. Following are the classes I am using

```
enter code here
public class VideoPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    static int[] arrayvid;
    private VideoView videoView;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View layout;
    TextView message;


    public VideoPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] arrayvid) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayvid = arrayvid;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayvid.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_layout, container, false);
        videoView = (VideoView)layout.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        message = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.message);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context, false);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout);
        return layout;

    }

    private Uri getPath(int id) {
        Log.i("Video", "num" + id);

        return Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.videoviewpager/raw/video_" + id);
    }

    public void play(int position) {
        videoView.setVideoURI(getPath(position+1));
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==(View)object;
    }


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    private int[] ids = {R.raw.video_1, R.raw.video_2,R.raw.video_3};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.video_pager);

        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new VideoPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,ids);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        //((VideoPagerAdapter) adapter).play(0);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(position==0){
                    ((VideoPagerAdapter) adapter).play(position);


                }
                if(position==1){

                    ((VideoPagerAdapter) adapter).play(position);
                }
                if(position==2){
                    ((VideoPagerAdapter) adapter).play(position);
                }
            }
//
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    private Uri getPath(int id) {
        Log.i("Video", "num" + id);

        return Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.videoviewpager/raw/video_" + id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to show video in viewpager is to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter`.

Under `getItem` of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, create instance of fragment where you will show the video. Play and Pause/Stop functionality of the video should be handled in Fragment's `onStart` & `onStop` lifecycle methods

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do your task by using the above answer recently i have done this task in my video make an empty fragment let as given below

```
class VideoPlayFragment(val file: File) : Fragment() {
    private var binding:FragmentVideoPlayBinding? = null
    private var mediaController: MediaController? = null
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_play, container, false)
        binding = FragmentVideoPlayBinding.bind(view)
        return view
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        playVideo()
    }
    private fun playVideo() {
        mediaController = MediaController(requireContext())
        mediaController?.setAnchorView(binding?.videoView)
        binding?.videoView?.setMediaController(mediaController)
        binding?.videoView?.setVideoPath(file.path)
        binding?.videoView?.start()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        stopVideo()
    }
    private fun stopVideo(){
        binding?.videoView?.stopPlayback()
    }

}

frament_video_play.xml

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hamza.fragmets.VideoPlayFragment">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

fragmentstateadapter

    class VideoPlayAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private var videoList:ArrayList<StoryModel>?=null
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return videoList?.size!!
    }
    fun update(videoList: ArrayList<StoryModel>){
        this.videoList = videoList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return videoList?.get(position)?.let { VideoPlayFragment(it.file) }!!
    }


}
```

and in the last simply attach this adapter to your viewpager2.I think this will help others i have spent more than a week on this