# Play videos in android videoview inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I want to play videos in side ViewPager i.e. I have few videos. I want to play them one by one on swiping. if i swipe from one page to second first should pause and second should start. 
I used ViewPager and VideoView.

In my case all videos from first two pager is start playing but i want to play only one which is visible.

Is there any way to do this?
Should i use any other approch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41378047/2798289